# Open3D, GLFW Error. No GLXFBConfigs returned

Tags: open3d

I want to visualize a pointcloud with open3d:

```
open3d.visualization.draw_geometries([geo])
```

where geo is a point cloud. However, upon running the above code, I get the following:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  [Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: GLX: No GLXFBConfigs returned
Subprocess failed (exit code: 134)
```

How to even start debugging this error?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by the GPU problem, but not direct problem of open3D. There have been some posts on the open3D GitHub issue.

For details, please refer to the Github issue for that problem.

https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/1598